# text inside noscript tags is being outputted as text and not form

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

As soon as I open my webpage without JavaScript my form in `<noscript>` tags is displayed as code but after I refresh it once it seems to be fine. Is there a way that I can display the form properly right after I disable JavaScript or is there a way I can reload the page once right after it loads when JavaScript is not enabled?

I've tried using meta refresh but I can't figure out a way to reload just once without the use of JavaScript.

here is the code:

```
<div id="JS" class="span4" style="display: none">
<h2 class="side">contact</h2>
<h3 class="side">message</h3>
<br><br>

                <form id="animate" >
                    <input id="name" name="Name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="25" >
                    <input id="email" name="Email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" maxlength="100">
                    <textarea id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Your Message" spellcheck="true" rows="6"></textarea>
                    <input id="spam" type="text" name="spam" style="display: none;" value=""/>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
                <div style="color: black; font-family: urwgroteskregular;" id="thanks">
                    <h2> Thank you, your message has been received.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4" id="noScript">
                <noscript>
                    <h2 class="side">contact</h2>
                    <h3 class="side">message</h3>
                    <br><br>
                    <form action='process.php' method="post" >
                        <input name="Name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="25">
                        <input  name="Email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" required="" maxlength="100">
                        <textarea  name="Message" placeholder="Your Message" spellcheck="true" rows="6" required=""></textarea>
                        <input  type="text" name="spam" style="display: none;" value=""/>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                </noscript>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                document.getElementById('JS').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('noScript').style.display = 'none';

            </script>
```

Comment: reloading a page that does not behave is not a solution. Post the code or a link to the page and we will find a way. The best is css

Comment: Stop making websites without JavaScript. It's 2013.

Comment: Sir,I know it's 2013, I have two forms, one that shows up if JS is enabled and one if it's not. When i switch from JS to no-JS , all of my code inside the noscript is shown as code and requires a refresh.

Comment: So hide the non-js form using js or post the html here so we can see why you need two forms: `document.write('<style>.nonjs { display:none}</style>')`

Comment: @mplungjan just add your code in the question

Comment: i added my code, the reason i need two forms is because my boss wants one if somebody loads the page without JS.

Comment: "When i switch from JS to no-JS , all of my code inside the noscript is shown as code and requires a refresh." Wait a minute. Are you saying the problem happens when you load the page with JS and then disable JS without reloading the page at all?

Comment: No, I disable JS and reload. Then after another reload the form appears.

Comment: On which browser(s) does this happen? Does it happen for the exact code you posted, when tested in isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's causing the `<noscript>` problem, but I do know you're on the wrong track with that approach.

Look at the two versions of the input form—they are identical except for these differences:

- The scripted version adds `id` attributes on the `<form>` and its elements.
- The `<noscript>` version adds `action` and `method` attributes to the `<form>`, and `required` attributes to several elements.

What you should do is have a *single* instance of this form and use it for both purposes. Add in all of the attributes from both versions of the form. The `id` attributes won't hurt anything in the no-JS case, and the `action`/`method` and `required` attributes won't hurt anything when you're handling the submission with JavaScript. (Just suppress the normal form submit with a `.preventDefault()` call as usual.)

So the form ends up like this:

```
<form id="animate" action="process.php" method="post" >
    <input id="name" name="Name" type="text" value=""
        placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="25">
    <input id="email" name="Email" type="text" value=""
        placeholder="Your E-mail" required="" maxlength="100">
    <textarea id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Your Message"
        spellcheck="true" rows="6" required="">
    </textarea>
    <input id="spam" type="text" name="spam"
        style="display: none;" value="">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your page also has `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags in the `<noscript>` section and the "Thank you" `<div>` in the script version, but you can hide and show those as needed using techniques like the ones suggested in the other answers.

Comment: yeah i used this way too, it's simpler and easier to understand. thanks anyways for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide the non-js form using js

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.write('<style>.nonjs { display:none}</style>');
<script>
```

Comment: If i did this wouldn't it be not displayed at all since the code is inside script tags?

Comment: This code would hide anything with class name of nonjs assuming CSS is active

Answer (score 0):

Most people deal with this problem by putting the class `no-js` on their HTML, and including the [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/), which removes it and replaces it with `js` — this way you can include the following CSS:

```
html.js #noScript {
  display: none;
}
```

…and scripted browsers won't display the second form.

If you don't want to include all of Modernizr, simply make sure your HTML had the class:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

Then include the following code in the `<head>`:

```
void function addScript(){
  var html = document.lastChild;
  html.className = html.className.replace('no-js','js');
}();
```

Scripted browsers will read and execute this script, which replaces the class. Now you can taylor your CSS to target only scripted browsers:

```
html.js #noScript {
  display: none;
}
```

Sorted! No need to make the page render the form, then remove it afterwards with JS. No need to nest it in `<noscript>`. Simply display it or not depending on script presence. The beauty with this technique is you can extend it: a classes `js-only` or `no-js-only` can be added to elements to specify which situation they should be shown in, etc.

Comment: This relies on CSS. What guarantees that a browser that has JavaScript disabled (or enabled) does not have CSS disabled?

Comment: Seems this would work exactly like my suggestion but with a lot more work

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela there is none. By default, the extra content renders. Hiding it is an enhancement.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know, I found it relatively painless to type that code and the surrounding paragraphs. Your comment is about a half of the extra characters needed to implement this — the key difference is that this is more extensible — you can test for `html.no-js` as well, and you can add other classes based on feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this tend to happen when you have mal-formed html within the noscript tags, for instance mixing html with xhtml (bad habbit) for example with a html page with a doc type of html:

```
<noscript>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</noscript>
```

instead of:

```
<noscript>
  <img src="image.jpg" >
</noscript>
```

seems to cause this, however this doesn't seem to cause issues outside of the no script tags, in at least all the main browsers anyway.

as for the above answers of using something other then a noscript tag.  forget modenizer ridiculously large amount of code to do something simple!

you could use a div with a class="noscript" have everything else hidden by default then use script to hide the noscript div and display other js-enabled content.
this has the advantage of also working should a js-enabled browser can't download your script, which can happen for a variety of reasons.  disadvantage of that approach is any external content within the  like an img tag will still be download by the browser pre-loader even if the browser has js enabled, so that's where a noscript tag can be better. best approach of course depends on what you are doing